# Is there any difference between string and array of one-digit strings in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, types

Quoting w3schools,

> Like many other popular programming languages, strings in Python are arrays of bytes representing unicode characters.

Is there any difference between `'abc'` and `['a', 'b', 'c']`? Is there a way to tell the difference between the first and the second example without using `type()`?

Comment: lots of different accessor methods .... `isinstance(x,str)` is another (but maybe thats like type...) ... i dont quite understand your question there are certainly similarities between them but they are really fundamentally distinct objects

Comment: Any difference? Yes, one's a string and one's a list. If you just `print` them they will not look at all alike. Is there some scenario in which you are actually having difficulty telling them apart?

Comment: That's a list of strings, not an array of bytes...

Comment: w3schools is notoriously terrible - don't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that what you quoted says "array of bytes". `['a', 'b', 'c']` is a list, not an array. They're talking about the internal representation as an array in memory, not how it's used in the language.

Many operations work differently on strings and lists. In particular, searching operations look for substrings in strings, but just single elements in lists.

```
s = 'abc'
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print('ab' in s) # prints True
print('ab' in l) # prints False
```

There are also many operations that only work with one or the other type. For example, regular expression matching will work on strings, not lists. Strings are immutable, so modification operations like `append()` and `pop()` only work with lists.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Python are *not* "arrays of Bytes".
They are first class objects - yes, the underlying object do
have a buffer where the bytes representing the unicode
characters are stored - but that is opaque.

Now, strings are *sequences* of one-character strings
(not bytes, not other type). As thus, most code that also accepts
or expects sequences of one-character strings will work with
a string of any-size, as well as any other such sequence,
such as a list of one-character strings as in your example.

Other than that, strings are fundamentally different from
"lists of strings". Probably the most used way to visualize
strings is a simple "print", and a print of a string and
such a list will differ enormously.

Then, if you need to find the diference in code, using
type, or calling `isinstance(myvar, str)` should be enough.